# Error when trying to minify objects

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

Getting ERROR Unexpected Token punc (,)

while trying to uglifyjs a .js file. The error occurs from this;

```
var requiredFields = {
    emailField,
    lastNameField,
    addressField,
    cityField,
    countryField,
    postField
  }
```

For some reason i cannot have a comma after the emailField. I am unsure why uglifyjs cannot parse a simple javascript object.
Also this gives same error;

```
var requiredFields = {
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
  }
```

I am running uglifyjs 3.4.3, the JS File where the code is included is ES5. 
To minify the code i run
    uglifyjs main.js --output main.min.js --compress --mangle

Comment: Which version of uglifyjs (v2 ,v3) are you using?  And is this ES5 or ES6 code you are working with?  And what options are you passing when you call uglifyjs?  A bit more information would go a long way toward having a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: For ES6+, I recommend using uglifyes.

Comment: The second example is not even in valid syntax, OP is doing JavaScript incorrectly. You can't use numbers as properties, unless they the quoted, e.g. `var requiredFields = {'1' : 1};`

Comment: Neither example is valid ES5.  In ES5, you need a property name **and** a property value.

Answer (score 1):

Does your uglify version support ES6's shorthand object notation?

`Please see the compatibility table for support for these notations. In non-supporting environments, these notations will lead to syntax errors.` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

In ES5 a JavaScript object will behave like JSON, so it expects you to already have some values initialized..
Object literals in ES5 need properties names AND values. And properties if unquoted shouldn't start with an integer!

Try

```
var requiredFields = {
 emailField:"",
 lastNameField:"",
 addressField:"",
 cityField:"",
 countryField:"",
 postField:""
}
```

Comment: Not really, ES6 allows this syntax `const num = 1; const obj = {num};` > `obj {num : 1}`

Comment: @kit you're right, we have to remind ourselves that these features are "new" (not really) but, if sometimes claims it works with javascript and it doesn't, a good way to debug the issue is to downgrade to ES5..

Comment: Code used is ES5, Not ES6. Post updated with more information